# GoogleVisualization: filtered selection items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

in google visualization i have implemented a dashboard with a table chart and some control filter.

Now assume that i have the following dataTable:

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Age');

 data.addRows([
      ['Customer1', 85],
      ['Customer2', 20],
      ['Customer3', 30],
    ]);
```

If i select the first row (Customer1) and i make:

```
var tmpData = table.getChart().getSelection();
var stringCustomer = data.getValue(tmpData.row, 0)
```

stringCustomer is "Customer1".

Now i filter the table chart to show only customer with an age ==30: i have only one row that is Customer3 and i select that row.

```
var tmpData = table.getChart().getSelection();
var stringCustomer = data.getValue(tmpData.row, 0)
```

With this code stringCustomer is always Customer1. How can i obtain Customer3? How getValue() return item of the showed items on the table chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection returns the indexes of the selected elements in the data *seen by the table or chart*, not the base DataTable.  The Dashboard passes a DataView to each ChartWrapper, which you can access via the `ChartWrapper#getDataTable` method.  Use this to get your data:

```
var selection = table.getChart().getSelection(),
    view = table.getDataTable(),
    stringCustomer;
// loop over all selected rows
for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    stringCustomer = view.getValue(selection[i].row, 0);
    // do something with stringCustomer
}
```